# SSH Agent Plugin v1.17 with Jenkins Declaritive Pipeline not working with Windows

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have been having issues getting my multibranch pipeline to perform git commands with an SSH key via the SSH Agent plugin on Windows.

I am able to successfully perform a git clone with the ssh from Git Bash on windows server that is running Jenkins.

In my pipeline log I am getting the following error when trying to use the sshagent plugin:

> [ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation... Could not find
>   ssh-agent: IOException: Cannot run program "ssh-agent": CreateProcess
>   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified Check if ssh-agent
>   is installed and in PATH [ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable
>   ssh-agent provider

I have seen that installing Apache Tomcat Native libraries has helped some people, but the steps for doing so are not very descriptive.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution of this issue?